# Error installing Ros Noetic in Debian Buster

Tags: ros, installation, debian, rasbperrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone.

I am installing Ros Noetic in my Raspberry PI 4 with Debian Buster because the [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/noetic/Installation/Debian) said that is fully supported. But when I try to execute the following commnad:

```
sudo apt install ros-noetic-desktop-full
```

The next error message is received:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-noetic-desktop-full
```

I obtain the same error trying to install kinetic or melofic and I don't know what to do. I know that Noetic release is very recent, but if the tutorial is written it should work.

Thanks in advance.

Best regrets.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/350055/error-installing-ros-noetic-in-debian-buster/) by [Alessandro Melino](https://answers.ros.org/users/52370/alessandro-melino/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2020-04-21

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pourya](https://answers.ros.org/users/21761/pourya/) on 2020-05-23**:
Hello

Today is May 23 and Noetic is not released yet!
Does anyone know the reason?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-05-23**:
Please don't post questions as answers. Either comment an existing answer, contribute your own answer if you have one, or post a new question.

I've converted your answer into a comment, but please keep it in mind for next time.

**Comment by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) on 2020-05-23**:
Following up; Noetic is now released https://www.openrobotics.org/blog/2020/5/23/noetic-ninjemys-the-last-official-ros-1-release

**Comment by [Dave_ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/55212/dave_ros/) on 2020-05-24**:
Hi, I am all seeing this error (Attempting to install on Debian 10 Buster)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Edit (2020-05-23): as @sloretz wrote in his comment:

> Following up; Noetic is now released https://www.openrobotics.org/blog/2020/5/23/noetic-ninjemys-the-last-official-ros-1-release

Note however:

> I am installing Ros Noetic in my Raspberry PI 4 with Debian Buster

Only the `amd64` and `arm64` platforms get binary packages of ROS Noetic. `armhf` packages are not built by the ROS buildfarm.

---

Original answer:

In addition to @RodBelaFarin's answer (which is correct), I would also add:

> I am installing Ros Noetic in my Raspberry PI 4 with Debian Buster **because the tutorial said that is fully supported.**

There is still this notice at the top of the page under the *Installation* heading:

[image]

This seems to pretty clearly communicate that at least as of today (2020-04-21), there is a high probability of some packages still missing.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) on 2020-04-21**:
This is correct, ROS Noetic is not yet released. There are packages in the `ros-testing` repo for those who brave enough to try them before release, though `desktop_full` isn't ready yet.

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros-testing/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-testing.list'
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From what I see [here](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_noetic_default.html) the desktop_full metapackage is not yet listed in the binary repos.

I guess you are really a bit too early and the documentation has just been released (probably before all debian binaries have been built?!).

My recommendation is to wait another 1-2 days and try it again.

---

Originally posted by [RodBelaFarin](https://answers.ros.org/users/3527/rodbelafarin/) with karma: 235 on 2020-04-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alessandro Melino](https://answers.ros.org/users/52370/alessandro-melino/) on 2020-04-21**:
Okay, thank you for your quick response. I will wait a bit and then try again.

**Comment by [lsw](https://answers.ros.org/users/33525/lsw/) on 2021-07-08**:
I try to install ros-noetic-desktop-full package in PI4 whose OS is buster today, but I still get the same error as below:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-noetic-desktop-full

**Comment by [Alessandro Melino](https://answers.ros.org/users/52370/alessandro-melino/) on 2021-07-09**:
Hello.
On Debian I achieved to make it work installing [Raspberry Pi OS 64 bits](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=275370).
Try a fresh install and I hope it works for you.